# SOQL & Custom relationships

Tags: soql, relationships, childrelationship

I'm trying to understand how to query using relationships,
I'm facing an issue I don't understand,

Here is what I'm trying to resolve :

[image]

I'm trying this, but it seems to be wrong..
Can you help me ?

[image]

I can't see any Certification__r object in my environment ...
Is that why I got this issue :

> ```
>                           Certification_Attempt__c.Certification__r.id
>                           ^
> ```
>
> Didn't understand
>   relationship 'Certification__r' in field path. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

If you have an idea, I'm lost...

Thanks

Edit :
A Schema Builder picture..
Doesn't it show there is no relation between the Certification, and the attempt ?

[image: A Schema Builder picture]

**------------FINAL EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED ------------**

Ok, there is plenty of things I didn't understand well, and I've been able to understand reading docs and working on it ;

I'll post my work for next people having troubles with this to understand,
hope it will help !

First, I didn't look so well to the **Certification Application Schema** and to the **Schema Builder** :

[image]

[image]

And my query and the results :

[image]

[image]

Thanks to you, helpers !

Comment: If you want to know whether the relationship exists, just go to the object definition of your Certification_Attempt__c object. There you will see the fields on that object, including any relationship fields like lookup or master-detail.

Comment: Humm... Sometimes I don't really understand how it works :
What about the FirstName and LastName, in the Account object ?

The only field required for an insert acc; is LastName.

The Name field, however, is the only that appears in both schema builder and object manager.
And I understand that Name is an automatic field given by : Salutation + FirstName + LastName

But where can I see, and change, the FirstName or LastName fields ?
That's one thing I didn't get yet.

Thanks for your help, anyway !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand child-to-parent relationships on queries. Check this [article](http://www.sfdc99.com/2013/06/09/example-how-to-write-a-cross-object-soql-query/) for further understanding.

Do you have a `Certification__c` custom object on the org, which is as a parent of `Certification_Attempt__c`, right?
If so then you have to make just:

`Certification__r.id` on the query.

**EDIT**

You have also to remove from query the `Certification_Attempt__c` field from query, as you already are querying that object.

The full correct query would be:

```
List<Certification_Attempt__c> oldCertAttempts = [Select Id, Name, Certification_Element__r.Id, Certification_Element__r.Name, Contact.Name, Contact.Account.Name
                                              From Certification_Attempt__c
                                              Where Status__c = 'Scheduled'];
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working ..
It seems to me, that the relationship is missing !

I mean, I have : Certification__c object and Certification_Attempt__c object

But no relation installed between them !
I'll edit my first message in order to have a schema builder picture to show it.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> When you use a relationship name in a query, you must use the relationship names without the __c. Instead, append an __r (underscore underscore r).

See the relevant sfdc help page:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

This means the __r is probably correct but you need to remove the Certification_Attempt__c. prefixes as you don't need to specify the object name for each field.

Comment: I'll look (again) at the salesforce doc, thanks !

But I just tested just to request Certification__r.id, and it doesn't work.

I got this error :
"
                              Certification__r
                              ^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:59
No such column 'Certification__r' on entity 'Certification_Attempt__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

(thanks, tho !)

Answer (score 1):

I think its

```
   Certification_Attempt__r.certification__c
```

If certification attempt is a child and certification is parent

You can access certification name like this

```
Certification_Attempt__r.certification__r.Name
```

Please check below posts:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm